# Logitech K860 keeps reverting to Windows keys

Tags: keyboard, windows, monterey, macos

My keyboard keeps reverting to Windows 10 after I restart my Mac. I do have it connected to Windows 10 on #1, but #2 was configured for Mac. When I restart my Mac, it reverts to Windows layout and has the Cmd and Opt keys reversed. Right now, I have to press `fn + O` for a long time to get it to switch back, but it's a) annoying and b) I shouldn't have to do this EVERY. SINGLE. TIME.

I have not been able to find any solution online for this. Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like a Tech Support issue with the keyboard.  What appears to be happening is when the Mac is shutdown/reboot, the connection is lost and the *keyboard* reverts to it’s default config.  Have you checked with Logitech to see why it’s doing this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because customer support questions are out of scope here as described in the [Help].

Comment: Like I said, I have had no luck finding any answers. At least your explanation about the "why" pointed me in a useful direction.

Comment: @Allan, I wish you wouldn't have voted this down and actually answered the question. I figured it out w/ the pointer you gave me. See below.

Comment: I very rarely vote down - only when things cause harm.  +1 to negate it because it’s not a bad question.

Comment: Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to fix it: I booted my Mac before I pressed the key to connect the keyboard to it. I entered the password on the Mac keyboard itself. I haven't tried waiting until it was fully booted, then connecting and typing it in on the K860. Either way, if you wait until the Mac has fully booted and then switch the connection key, all is well.

Comment: Glad you found a fix/workaround!  Thanks for sharing so other who run into this have a potential solution